# Invoke other webmethod with SoapExtension

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, asmx, soap-extension

I've a WSDL defining a web service named **CalendarService**:

```
<soap:address location="http://example.com/calendar"/>
```

The WSDL defines following methods:

```
String setDate(String date)
int setTime(int time)
```

CalendarService is not deployed anywhere.
**CalendarServiceProxy** is a proxy generated from CalendarService WSDL.

---

I've a web service named **DummyService** accessible at "**http://example.com/dummy**"

DummyService has following methods:

```
String dummyMethod(String foo)
```

DummyService is deployed on IIS.

---

I wonder if it is possible to write a SoapExtension so that all calls from CalendarServiceProxy to all methods defined in the CalendarService WSDL invoke the method dummyMethod of DummyService. So that the method dummyMethod gets as parameter the serialized incoming SOAP message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is practical using a SoapExtension.

This sort of thing is quite possible with WCF, however.

---

Some WCF Links:

- [WCF Developer's Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)
- [Beginner's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx)
- [Extending WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733848.aspx)
- I think you'll want [Extending Dispatchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734665.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I also have no idea how to solve this with WCF, could you please point me in the right direction by listing a few links?